# Forbidden access in Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, heroku-cli

My app hosted in Heroku and using Mysql ClearDB and my app is built under laravel and it is accessed very fine but when am trying to access one of URL I get

```
You don't have permission to access /bundles/ on this server.
```

And When I run command

```
heroku run php artisan clear:cache
```

I get an error

```
Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.
```

Also when I try to run command

```
heroku run php artisan db:seed
```

I get error below

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user 'XXXXXXXX'@'ec2-XXXX.amazonaws.com' for  table 'model_has_roles' (SQL: insert into `model_has_roles` (`model_id`, ` model_type`, `role_id`) values (1, App\User, 11))
```

What is the problem here

Comment: Is `/bundles/` a Laravel route, or a folder in `public`? What cache driver are you using?

Comment: yes bundles/ is the route and am using file as my cache drive @ceejayoz

Comment: Please show us the `Route::get` definition you're using. Also note that `heroku run php artisan clear:cache` won't do anything if you're using the `file` cache driver. It clears the cache just on the temporary dyno `heroku run` launches.